ggplot: force unused guide to display
I am developing a general plot function.
I want to annotate this plot with a large block of text (info).
However, since my plots may have 1 or many facet rows/columns,
using labs(tag=info), geom_text or annotate as suggested
here or
here
is a big pain to get reasonable spacing.
The thing is: ggplot can already compute reasonable spacing --- for legends. So, I want to hijack the legend to display my info. If I have any existing guide (e.g. colour), I can add concatenate info as shown below. However, this only works if the "colour" aesthetic is used in the plot. I would like a reliable way to add to the legend and force it to be displayed, perhaps with a dummy aesthetic.
library('ggplot2')

add.info = function(g,info,guide='colour'){
  label = sprintf('%s\n\n%s',info,g$label[[guide]])
  args = setNames(list(label),guide)
  g = g + do.call(labs,args)
}

X = data.frame(x=1,y=1,z=1)
g = ggplot(X,aes(x=x,y=y,color=z)) +
  geom_point()
g = add.info(g,'hello world',guide='colour')
print(g)


This sound like a use case for guide_custom which was introduced in ggplot2 3.5.0:
library("ggplot2")

X <- data.frame(x = 1, y = 1, z = 1)
g <- ggplot(X, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point()

g +
  guides(
    custom = guide_custom(
      grid::textGrob(label = "hello world"),
      title = "Info"
    )
  )



Brilliant! Thank you so much! Unfortunately, the I cannot update the ggplot2 version on the HPC but ... I think I can work something from here.
